# Looking for an http "Tee"

Tags: http

I am looking for a http "tee" command/servlet/{python,perl}-script.

Basically I want to distribute an http post request to a number of machines. One machine or process sits on one port and receives an http request and just sends it out to a number of other machines in the same format. The response of the downstream servers can be ignored and the http tee would always return HTTP_OK with no output ...

It sounds so simple that it should already exist. Does it?

Comment: How complex is your distribution network? I'm tempted to say that this should just be a few lines of PHP with a CURL call. But if you need to do some complex load-balancing, then maybe not...

Answer (score 0):

A slow version of http tee may be created by using nc.

```
mknod backpipe p
while [[ true ]] ; do (nc -l YOUR_MAIN_PORT 0<backpipe | tee >( cat > /dev/tcp/YOUR_TEE_HOST/PORT ) | nc YOUR_BACKEND_HOST YOUR_BACKEND_PORT | tee -a outflow 1>backpipe); done
```